# How to get real time Redis key expiry notification

Tags: redis

I understand that Redis key expiry event/notification is not real time.
https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/#timing-of-expired-events

Is there any way to get real time Redis expiry event ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Redis isn't designed to provide this functionality. This expiry is used to clear out things like session after some certain time. What are you trying to accomplish with this behaviour?

Comment: We want to store some items which will expire and wanted to utilize the Redis's TTL behaviour for this. But i guess this is not the right idea to couple expiry of an item with Redi's TTL because we won't be sure when was the item expired and to execute real time operations based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go about it this way. I am not sure the scale of the project, but having a queue like activeMQ that has a delayed deliver will work really well for the use case you described.

So you would send it on arrival and when the TTL expires it will send the payload to the consumer to do the processing.

I think Redis has some queuing tools that might provide similar functionality if you want to avoid adding something new to your stack.

https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-4-task-queues/